# How to set up a virtual environment in PHP for managing third party libraries?

Tags: php, virtualenv

I'm coming from python where pip and virtualenv make it very simple to manage dependencies without polluting the global interpreter of Python. I understand php has Composer and virtPHP, but is there any way to specify the directory that the virtual environment gets installed in, instead of virtPHP defaulting to ~/.virtPHP ?

With Python, I usually install it in my applications root directory under the name "venv" and then gitignore it. Are there other tools that I am unaware of that makes this easy in PHP?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to do... You want to add your libraries as global to access it through your different projects?

Comment: No, I don't want to pollute my global php interpreter with packages that are unique to certain projects. I want to isolate different environments for each specific app.

Comment: Wat do you mean by "pollute my global php interpreter"? There's no such thing, as you usually install your packages **per application** and not globally

Answer (score 0):

Probably [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) that you need. What it does is quite simple. You write a json file with the dependencies you need & some project details and when using "composer install" a folder "vendors" with the dependencies you specified will be added to your project folder.

And when you delete your projet folder, all dependencies are gone too.

Comment: Prolly should make note of the `autoloader` as well here